# Ruby : What changes needed to make test-unit-1.2.3 working with Ruby-2.4.1

Tags: ruby, testunit

I am new to Ruby Development. Now i am working on ruby test-framework code which was working fine with Ruby-1.8.7
Now i want to upgrade ruby for this framework. I have found that test-unit-1.2.3 is included in Ruby-1.8.7 so i have installed it separately with Ruby-2.4.1.
Currently i am facing method missing issue ["register_autorunner"] with this combination. Because these method have not been used in ruby-1.8.7

Can anyone please tell me other changes needed to make this combination [Ruby-2.4.1 , test-unit-1.2.3] working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should update to TestUnit 3.x, which will have a higher chance of working with Ruby 2.x. Then you need to figure out the changes between Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 2.4.1, and how to fix your existing code, which is most likely broken, even after you have fixed/updated your unit test configuration.

Also, consider a switch to Minitest or Rspec, as they are a lot more popular today, so it will be easier to find examples and supporting tools for them. Minitest is also the default test framework used by Ruby on Rails currently.

References:

https://www.jetbrains.com/research/devecosystem-2017/ruby/

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/testing.html